# Button em Fragment android

Tags: java, android

Possuo um *Fragment* e este fragmento, possui um *FloatingActionButton*.

Invoco o método *onClickListener*:

```
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabAddEventos);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            adicionarEvento(v);
        }
    });
```

Ao clicar, invoco o método adicionarEvento passando a View como parâmetro para criar um *Dialog* com vários campos de *Edit Text* e *Button*.

```
public void adicionarEvento(View view) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(view.getContext());
    EditText etEventos_nome = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etEventos_nome);
    Button btn_eventos_confirmar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_eventos_confirmar);
    btn_eventos_confirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

O erro ocorre no *Context* ou *View* do Dialog, travando o aplicativo.

Comment: Ta muito confusa a sua pergunta, qual é o erro? Posta ele aqui também

Comment: Refiz a pergunta. Não apresenta erro, no entanto, trava o app ao invocar o **setOnClickListener()** de Button. Resumindo, a lógica é a seguinte:
Um Fragment possui um FloatingActionButton que abre um Dialog, este último possui um Button.

Comment: Tenta fazer o seguinte: **Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());** no lugar do **Dialog dialog = new Dialog(view.getContext());**, pois esse **view.getContext()** está pegando o contexto do método, e não da classe

Comment: Editei minha resposta abaixo, vê se resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                dialogFragment = new DialogExample();
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                dialogFragment.show(fragmentManager,"");
            }
        });
```

Classe **DialogExample**

```
public class DialogExample extends DialogFragment {

private static View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_example, null);

    int width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_width);
    int height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_height);
    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);

    EditText etEventos_nome = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etEventos_nome);
    Button btn_eventos_confirmar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_eventos_confirmar);
    btn_eventos_confirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    return view;


}
```

}

xml **dialog_example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_eventos_confirmar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEventos_nome"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="aaaaa" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: O que sua resposta tem haver com a necessidade dele ?

Answer (score 1):

`void   onClick(View v)`

View v: Representa a view que foi clicada, neste caso seria como você estivesse chamando:

```
adicionarEventos(floatActionButton);
```

e depois você tenta pegar uma view no fab com um id que não existe

```
EditText etEventos_nome = (EditText) floatActionButton.findViewById(R.id.etEventos_nome);
```